# Removing NULL , NAN, empty space from PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-1.6

I have a dataframe in PySpark which contains empty space, Null, and Nan. 
I want to remove rows which have any of those. I tried below commands, but, nothing seems to work.

```
myDF.na.drop().show()
myDF.na.drop(how='any').show()
```

Below is the dataframe:

```
+---+----------+----------+-----+-----+
|age|  category|      date|empId| name|
+---+----------+----------+-----+-----+
| 25|electronic|17-01-2018|  101|  abc|
| 24|    sports|16-01-2018|  102|  def|
| 23|electronic|17-01-2018|  103|  hhh|
| 23|electronic|16-01-2018|  104|  yyy|
| 29|       men|12-01-2018|  105| ajay|
| 31|      kids|17-01-2018|  106|vijay|
|   |       Men|       nan|  107|Sumit|
+---+----------+----------+-----+-----+
```

What am I missing? What is the best way to tackle NULL, Nan or empty spaces so that there is no problem in the actual calculation?

Comment: Can you pls confirm that you are in Spark *1.6*, as tagged?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Spark 1.6

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NaN` (not a number) has different meaning that `NULL` and empty string is just a normal value (can be converted to NULL automatically with csv reader) so `na.drop` won't match these.

You can convert all to null and drop

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, isnan, when, trim

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("", 1, 2.0), ("foo", None, 3.0), ("bar", 1, float("NaN")), 
    ("good", 42, 42.0)])

def to_null(c):
    return when(~(col(c).isNull() | isnan(col(c)) | (trim(col(c)) == "")), col(c))


df.select([to_null(c).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).na.drop().show()
# +----+---+----+
# |  _1| _2|  _3|
# +----+---+----+
# |good| 42|42.0|
# +----+---+----+
```

Comment: It helped to solve my problem. However, any idea why myDF.na.drop().show() OR myDF.na.drop(how='any').show() didn't work on the fly?

Comment: Because a) empty or blank string is not NULL, b) NaN is not NULL. Empty string is not even related and NaN has different meaning than NULL.

Comment: Tested above scenario on Spark 3.0, `df.na.drop()` removes rows containing `null` and `NaN` values. So you just need to add a check for empty string ''

Answer (score 0):

Maybe in your case it is not important but this code (modifed answer of Alper t. Turker) can handle different datatypes accordingly. The dataTypes can vary according your DataFrame of course. (tested on Spark version: 2.4)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, isnan, when, trim

# Find out dataType and act accordingly
def to_null_bool(c, dt):
    if df == "double":
        return c.isNull() | isnan(c)
    elif df == "string":
        return ~c.isNull() & (trim(c) != "")
    else:
        return ~c.isNull()

# Only keep columns with not empty strings
def to_null(c, dt):
    c = col(c)
    return when(to_null_bool(c, dt), c)

df.select([to_null(c, dt[1]).alias(c) for c, dt in zip(df.columns, df.dtypes)]).na.drop(how="any").show()
```